# Android: Switch touch event focus view

Tags: android, android-view, android-touch-event

I am catching the touch events on an `ImageView`, when I touch it the view gets hidden and all the view is covered by a `FrameLayout`. I need that the touch events on the image view to stop and to transfer a new touch event on the new `layout`, which is covering this `ImageView`.

I have tried something like this:

```
imageView.setOnTouchEventListener { v, event ->
    imageView.clearFocus()
    frameLayout.requestFocus()
    return false
}
```

I have tried things as `dispatchEvent` but it does not work in this case since the `imageView` is just a little part of the whole screen and the `frameLayout` covers all the screen.

Anyways I always end up with the same problem, where I have to lift my finger and touch the screen again so the imageView looses the old touch event and finally the framelayout starts catching it. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Could you remove the touch listener from the `ImageView` after it has been clicked, then add a touch listener to the `FrameLayout`?

Comment: I already did it, it did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement touch event listener on both ImageView and FrameLayout then use a variable to know ImageView is touched or not. something like this:

```
boolean imageViewIsTouched = false;

imageView.setOnTouchEventListener { v, event ->
    if(!imageViewIsTouched){
         //do something
         imageViewIsTouched = true;
    }
    return false
}

frameLayout.setOnTouchEventListener { v, event ->
    if(imageViewIsTouched){
       //do something
    }
    return false
}
```